# Why is blenders hair system making spikes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am using a hair/particle system but all of the hairs look like spikes not hair:

[image]

How can I set it so they all have a consistent thickness and how can I adjust the thickness?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58761/why-does-my-hair-render-as-a-cone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting for hair particles in cycles are in *Particles > Cycles Hair Rendering* and *Particles > Cycles Hair Settings*.

To make the hairs a constant thickness, set the root and tip thickness settings to the same value and disable *Close Tip*:

[image]

To get a cylinder-like result, you will also have to disable *Particles > Cycles Hair Rendering > Cull Back-faces* so the backs of faces are not hidden:

[image]

[See the manual for more information](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/geometry.html#cycles-settings-scene-render-geometry).

Comment: The link is broken. Anyway can u plz give in short comment what will be the setting for normal human hairs. Root, tip and close tip (on or off)

Comment: @atek Thanks for the heads up. I couldn't find a manual link which exactly corresponded to the [old wiki page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150414065136/http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Hair_Rendering), but I linked the most appropriate one I could find. As for human hairs, this question was specifically about making uniform-width hair. You are welcome to ask a new question about human hairs though.